# Changing my regex to no longer have a loop

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex that does what I want, which is get all the numbers 31 or below and puts them on their own line. Now what I want to do is no longer have a loop in this, but I'm not sure how to do this and need some help.

```
x = IO.read(path)
x.split(/\D+/).select {|n| n.to_i >= 0 && n.to_i < 32 && n.length < 3}.join("\n")
```

Input

```
1
10
12
18 19 20
21 22 ----asdfadsf 23t24####25,26,27,
28!
29.
30
31
32
33
01 02 03x04x05x06x07x08x09
001
002
1x1a
    35


-87 76 101 10057

-13 -1.5
```

Output- 1
10
12
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
1
1
13
1
5
(each one of those on it's own line, but I didn't want to make it too long)

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: All numbers that are 31 or below are of the form /[1-3]?[0-9]/  so if you just use that instead of \D+ you should be able to get rid of the loop

Comment: @AhmedMasud your regex matches "33" through "39" as well. Numeric range matching isn't really a good application for regexes.

Comment: @Palpatim true that... you can regex it a bit better with something like /[1-2]?[0-9]|3[01]/  ... however what he's doing can be parsed using a regex rather than an extra engine that does numeric evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scan` with lookahead and lookbehind:

```
puts x.scan(/(?<!\d)([0-2]?\d|3[0-1])(?!\d)/).join("\n")
```

Play with the regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/aO9oM5)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this many ways.  I would first pull out the string representations of the the numbers and put them in an array:

```
str.scan(/\d+/).select { |n| n.to_i < 32 }
   .map { |s| (s[0,2]=='00') ? s[1..-1] : s }
  #=> [ "1", "10", "12", "18",  "19",  "20",` "21", "22", "23", "24", "25",
  #    "26", "27", "28", "29",  "30",  "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05",
  #    "06", "07", "08", "09",  "01",  "02",  "1",  "1", "13",  "1",  "5"]
```

Now you can print out the results in whatever format you want.  You said you didn't want the lines too long.  Then you might do something like this:

```
def print_it(str, max_line_len, nbr_spacers)
  arr = str.scan(/\d+/).select { |n| n.to_i < 32 }
           .map { |s| (s[0,2]=='00') ? s[1..-1] : s }
  fld_width = arr.max_by(&:size).size + nbr_spacers
  arr.each_slice(max_line_len/fld_width)
     .each { |slice| puts slice.map { |s| s.rjust(fld_width) }.join }
end

print_it(str, 60, 3)
    1   10   12   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   27   28   29   30   31   01   02   03   04   05   06   07
   08   09   01   02    1    1   13    1    5
```

The bit

```
.map { |s| (s[0,2]=='00') ? s[1..-1] : s }
```

is to reduce two leading zeros to just one, which affects two entries (`'001'` and `'002'`).  If you don't care about that, just eliminate that part of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here is easy single regexp that match numbers 1 to 31

```
^(?:3[01]|[12]?[0-9])$
```

It works but if your not sure you can test it by throwing numbers :)